# How do you parse the Signature element from a SAML response using xmlcrypto?

Tags: saml-2.0, xml-signature

I am trying to use [xmlcrypto](https://github.com/yaronn/xml-crypto) to parse out and validate the `<ds:Signature>` element from a SAML response. The response was received from my [SSOCircle](http://www.ssocircle.com/en/) test Identity Provider (see below for complete SAML Response) and appears to be a standard `samlp` response which contains an Assertion that has been correctly signed using an xml digital signature.

Here is the code I am using. This has been taken from the xmlcrypto help on github.

**CoffeeScript**

```
validateSignature: (saml) ->
    doc = new @xmldom.DOMParser().parseFromString saml
    signature = @xmlCrypto.xpath(doc, "/*/*[local-name(.)='Signature' and namespace-uri(.)='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#']")[0]
    signed = new @xmlCrypto.SignedXml null, idAttribute: 'AssertionID'
    signed.loadSignature signature.toString() # this line fails as signature is undefined
```

As you can see, the code above uses the `xmlCrypto.xpath()` function to retrieve the `<ds:Signature>` element from the parsed xml document, however the result of this function is always `undefined`

**SAML Response**

```
<samlp:Response ID="s208442fc7db110e1a6e9df3f6f1c66ff8cd64219c" InResponseTo="_de666b2c-1b3c-de17-1cde-0d97211b1ddd" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2014-07-29T14:33:45Z" Destination="https://localhost/security/saml2/response" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        </samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion ID="s2b6bb561a07e30465057af94c7aff92f8b0e11143" IssueInstant="2014-07-29T14:33:45Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml:Issuer>http://idp.ssocircle.com</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <ds:Reference URI="#s2b6bb561a07e30465057af94c7aff92f8b0e11143">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                    <ds:DigestValue>Lvm7MFE/Chy3gR97omBDlkNmwO0=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>GUBxQmOF0yWvC [...] YslXU=</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIICjDCCAXSg [...] WjeU5FLwDZR0Q=</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" NameQualifier="http://idp.ssocircle.com">biofractal@gmail.com</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="_de666b2c-1b3c-de17-1cde-0d97211b1ddd" NotOnOrAfter="2014-07-29T14:43:45Z" Recipient="https://localhost/security/saml2/response" />
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2014-07-29T14:23:45Z" NotOnOrAfter="2014-07-29T14:43:45Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>gp-sso-localhost</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-07-29T08:47:22Z" SessionIndex="s2cd309df973ca61fd0b359e968208375f65d35b01">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the xpath, which is specific for saml that contains its signature in the root. To find the signature within the inner assertion you need to use the following line, with the xpath updated:

```
signature = @xmlCrypto.xpath(doc, ".//*[local-name(.)='Signature' and namespace-uri(.)='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#']")[0]
```